# loop of canvas transform causes chrome to omit part of the loop

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm now praticing canvas and encounter a chrome bug when using loop of transform to create a "ring" of text.

The link is here: http://herophuong.byethost7.com/javascript/slideshow

Openning it with Opera and Firefox makes the script done successfully, while with chrome, the result is not what it's supposed to be (the ring loses some parts or doesn't appear at all). If I take time to walk through the script step by step with the webkit inspector (built-in chrome), the script will be executed successfully though.

Is there any workaround for the bug or I have to wait for newer version of Chrome? My current version is 19.0.1084.52.

Some screenshot:

[image: HTML5 Slideshow in Firefox]
[image: HTML5 Slideshow in Chrome]

Comment: Just tested this with chrome 19.0.1084.52 . I can't see a chrome bug here.

Comment: Other fact is that I'm using kubuntu, i.e the Chrome is Chrome Linux

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with chrome 19.0.1084.52 on Linux Ubuntu 12.10 (Long Time Support). I can't say why it's not working, check if canvas text is supported in your chrome with this:

```
typeof document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').fillText === "function"
```

It might be that it's somehow disabled on your computer.

Comment: I have changed the screenshot to other slide to show that fillText is actually working. The weird part is that it doesn't render text-shadow and only 1 part of the ring.

Comment: Good Question! That looks like really weird stuff for me. I've tested all slides and effects but still no bug... I'll keep this answer a while for further visitors.